# Special characters in batch

Tags: batch-file

I'm using windows 7, and I'd like to create menus, progress bars, etc. with special characters like this. How to do this?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The point is - you need to use the UTF-8 Format, [take a look](http://ss64.org/viewtopic.php?id=1499):

Step 1] Create a new CMD script in the "UTF 8" format. (PsPad or Notepad++ editors can do this)

Step 2] Leave an empty blank line on the very first line. The UTF 8 header is stored there.

Step 3] Copy paste the code below:

```
@echo off
CHCP 65001
:: *****************************************************************************
:: * Author: Gustaaf von Pickartz.                                             *
:: * Date Created: 22nd July, 2012.                                            *
:: * ------------------------------------------------------------------------- *
:: * This program is provided as is and for fair use distribution.             *
:: * Give credit where credit is due to the author in your own script.         *
:: * ------------------------------------------------------------------------- *
:: *****************************************************************************
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

:: Progress Bar
 SET PRG0=[░░░░░░░░░░]
 SET PRG1=[▓░░░░░░░░░]
 SET PRG2=[▓▓░░░░░░░░]
 SET PRG3=[▓▓▓░░░░░░░]
 SET PRG4=[▓▓▓▓░░░░░░]
 SET PRG5=[▓▓▓▓▓░░░░░]
 SET PRG6=[▓▓▓▓▓▓░░░░]
 SET PRG7=[▓▓▓▓▓▓▓░░░]
 SET PRG8=[▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓░░]
 SET PRG9=[▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓░]
SET PRG10=[▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓]

:: Star
 SET STR1=/
 SET STR2=--
 SET STR3=\
 SET STR4=^|

:: Please note there are special ASCII insertions in the SET BKSPC= declaration below. 80x backspace characters are inserted. ASCII Value 08=[BS]
:: Be sure to verify they are still there when you cut and paste from the web with your text editor (Notepad++ or PsPad). Insert them if missing, otherwise this script will not work...
SET BKSPC=


:Begin_Main
echo.
echo.
Echo Simple Animated star.
FOR /L %%I IN (1,1,400) DO (
<NUL (SET/P Z= PROGRESS: │)
<NUL (SET/P Z=%BKSPC%)
<NUL (SET/P Z= PROGRESS: /)
<NUL (SET/P Z=%BKSPC%)
<NUL (SET/P Z= PROGRESS: ─)
<NUL (SET/P Z=%BKSPC%)
<NUL (SET/P Z= PROGRESS: \)
<NUL (SET/P Z=%BKSPC%)
)

echo.
echo.
Echo Simple Progress bar indicator
FOR /L %%I IN (0,1,10) DO (
IF %%I LEQ 9 (SET TIC=0%%I) ELSE (SET TIC=%%I)
<NUL (SET/P Z=[!TIC!/10] PROGRESS: !PRG%%I!)
>NUL PING -n 2 localhost
<NUL (SET/P Z=%BKSPC%)
)

echo.
echo.
Echo Combined Progress bar and animated star...
FOR /L %%I IN (0,1,10) DO (
IF %%I LEQ 9 (SET TIC=0%%I) ELSE (SET TIC=%%I)
<NUL (SET/P Z=[!TIC!/10] PROGRESS: !PRG%%I!)
<NUL (SET/P Z=%BKSPC%)
    FOR /L %%J IN (1,1,400) DO (
    <NUL (SET/P Z=[!TIC!/10] PROGRESS: !PRG%%I! │)
    <NUL (SET/P Z=%BKSPC%)
    <NUL (SET/P Z=[!TIC!/10] PROGRESS: !PRG%%I! /)
    <NUL (SET/P Z=%BKSPC%)
    <NUL (SET/P Z=[!TIC!/10] PROGRESS: !PRG%%I! ─)
    <NUL (SET/P Z=%BKSPC%)
    <NUL (SET/P Z=[!TIC!/10] PROGRESS: !PRG%%I! \)
    <NUL (SET/P Z=%BKSPC%)
    )
<NUL (SET/P Z=%BKSPC%)
)
```

Step 4] Be sure to "insert" 80x  backspace ASCII characters at the SET BKSPC= (http://columbia.edu/kermit/ascii.html)

Step 5] Be sure you set your CMD console font to the True Type font, not the raster.

Comment: the link you posted is broken.

Comment: @cascading-style Thank you, removed brocken link

Comment: Maybe use this one instead: http://www.columbia.edu/kermit/ascii.html

Comment: @cascading-style Thank you, added new link instead.